# Keychain won't unlock from Jenkins script unless user logged in

Tags: xcode, macos, hudson, jenkins, keychain

I'm running a Jenkins CI server on an OS X machine. The server is running as a standard user 'john', and is started by running launchctl. One of the things this server does is build XCode projects using keys and certificates stored in a keychain 'xcode.keychain':

Jenkins (which is running under the user 'john' according to activity monitor) calls these commands from a script when the user presses a button on the web interface.

```
security default-keychain -s /Users/john/Library/Keychains/xcode.keychain
security unlock-keychain -p password /Users/john/Library/Keychains/xcode.keychain
xcodebuild ...
```

If I happen to be logged into the server as 'john' via the UI, the keychain gets unlocked properly when Jenkins calls those commands. But, if I'm not logged in, xcode.keychain doesn't get unlocked and the build fails. Any ideas?

Comment: Moving all the keys and certs into the System.keychain fixed this problem. I'm guessing it has something to do with Jenkins running from launchctl, but still curious why exactly it wasn't working before.

Comment: How exactly did you do this? I tried to replicate your solution, but I still get an error :(

Comment: YMMV, but I just moved my keys and certs to the system keychain as recommended above and it worked for me.

Comment: Reason and solution explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9482707/111823

Comment: Dragging the key with certificate to the System keychain worked for me, and doesn't require putting my keychain password in a script, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running Jenkins without launchd works. I used the following command:

```
sudo su jenkins -c "JENKINS_HOME=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home /Library/Application\ Support/Jenkins/jenkins-runner.sh"
```

Comment: Running a CI/CD System such as Jenkins with `super user do` (sudo) seems a bad idea for the security concerns.

Answer (score 13):

I had to:

1. Right-click on the private key in my keychain that my build process
   was trying to use
2. Click "Get Info"
3. Then the "Access Control" tab.
4. You can add specific apps (like "codesign") to the list of apps that
   are allowed access to that key, or just allow access from all applications.

This cleared it up for me.

More info in these comments:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12235462/544130
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14761060/544130

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled upon the exact same issue recently.

`security list-keychains -s /Users/john/Library/Keychains/xcode.keychain` probably will fix your problem. Let me know if it works.

Recently I found a solution to this over there: [Missing certificates and keys in the keychain while using Jenkins/Hudson as Continuous Integration for iOS and Mac development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827874/missing-certificates-and-keys-in-the-keychain-while-using-jenkins-hudson-as-cont/7805400#7805400)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Jenkins.app](https://github.com/stisti/jenkins-app), an alternative way to run Jenkins. It runs Jenkins in a user session, so Keychain should not be a problem.