# xcodebuild on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, xcodebuild

I am getting frustrated with this and will really appreciate any help

We set up jenkins for our CI environment on Mac OSX for building our xcode project. Configured everything with SVn so that it syncs and all but when it comes to build

Code Sign error : There are no valid certificate/private key pairs in the default keychain

Jenkins as far as i know is running under the daemon and i am logged in as myself on that machine so after hours of looking i copied the Iphone Developer Certificates from the login.keychain to the system.keychain too and now get this error . A valid provisioning profile matching the appliacation's IDentifier "MZCZ.... . Icacher" could not be found

So i deleted it

As somebody suggested , I even set up the session create to info.plist too  as suggested on here [Missing certificates and keys in the keychain while using Jenkins/Hudson as Continuous Integration for iOS and Mac development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827874/missing-certificates-and-keys-in-the-keychain-while-using-jenkins-hudson-as-cont/9482707#9482707)

Did this too

To keep a compartmentalized keychain for Jenkins/Hudson, I moved the launchctl item from

/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
to

/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/Library/LaunchAgents/org.jenkins-ci.plist

This is how my launch Daemon org.jenkins-ci.plist looks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>JENKINS_HOME</key>
        <string>/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home</string>
    </dict>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>daemon</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.jenkins-ci</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
                <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>/Library/Application Support/Jenkins/jenkins-runner.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>daemon</string>
    <key>SessionCreate</key>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Please help i have run out of options

Answer (score 0):

We just had this problem.  You need to add the SessionCreate key, but in your example you forgot to add `<true/>` after it.