# mac security command needs write permissions when run by daemon?

Tags: macos, tomcat, keychain, launchd

I'm tasked with moving a Tomcat/Jenkins installation from the deprecated (and now removed in Yosemite) SystemStarter framework to launchd.  It launches and runs fine as a "build" user, except for one thing.  Part of our build process involves calling the "security" command to manipulate the keychain.  This is failing as follows:

```
security: cert import failed: write permissions error
security: problem decoding
```

If I ssh into the build machine and launch Tomcat from a command prompt, via bin/startup.sh, then the call to `security` doesn't complain.  It only complains when I launch Tomcat via launchd.  My plist looks like this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.apache.tomcat</string>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>builduser</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/builduser</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/builduser/bin/tomcat.sh</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CATALINA_HOME</key>
        <string>/Users/builduser/Tomcat</string>
        <key>CATALINA_OPTS</key>
        <string>-Djava.awt.headless=true</string>
        <key>JAVA_OPTS</key>
        <string>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

plist is located in /Library/LaunchDaemons and tomcat.sh is just a wrapper that launches tomcat and then waits for the process to die.

Answer (score 4):

I've just faced similar problem by myself - I was decoding `.mobileprovision` file using

`cmd -D -i <path_to_file>`

Everything works locally and over SSH, but executed from Python app was throwing `security: cert import failed: write permissions error`

I found [this walkaround](https://github.com/autopkg/recipes/commit/657b2eb51f22dd14d44b90a0ae7a1d3e3313087e) for what seems to be the same issue and they ended up with creating temporary `keychain` and using it in `security` command:

`cmd -D -k <specific_keychain> -i <path_to_file>`

I'm not 100% sure if this is proper solution to this problem, but it certainly works well.

Answer (score 3):

I just implemented Dariusz's workaround and it works magic. 
In my quest for a solution to this issue I also came across a great answer by user joensson over here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9482707/1074558

The gist is add these keys to your plist.

```
<key>SessionCreate</key>
<true/>
<key>UserName</key>
<string>builduser</string>
```

I see you already have the `UserName` set, so it'll just be the `SessionCreate` key.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue, on further inspection, there seemed to be a mixup between which keychain to use when I was on the machine vs running via ssh and also through my application.

Before trying things, run `security default-keychain` and check that the keychain you expect is the one being used. If it is not, you can pass the correct one through using the -k flag as above in Dariusz's answer. It may be a keychain corruption issue as well, so you can try resetting or fixing the keychain.

Remember there is both `~/Library/Keychains` and `Library/Keychains`

Answer (score 0):

If you have configuration management working for your keychain (ansible/chef/etc.)
Another solution is resetting the keychain/deleting the "corrupted" keychain and working with a new one.