# Error code 9216 when attempting to access keychain password in LaunchAgent

Tags: macos, keychain, launchd, launchdagent, ionicsecurity

There are several other questions that discuss accessing the keychain from LaunchAgents.

One of the key ones is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9482707/790075) where [joensson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1237974/joensson) mentions that you need to set a `<SessionCreate>` in your app plist.

I have done that, and now my application plist looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/IonicFSWatcher.app/Contents/MacOS/ionic-fs-watcher</string>
        <string>--debug</string>
        <string>/Users/timothy/ionicprotected</string>
        <string>--scan</string>
    </array>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>timothy</string>
    <key>SessionCreate</key>
    <true />
  </dict>
</plist>
```

The app is a python application, which was created with [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), packaged using [pkgbuild](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgbuild.1.html), and installed [via the command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72226/installing-pkg-with-terminal).

The application runs fine when run from the command line.  If the application is run for the first time, the user gets a prompt to allow access to the keychain, the app continues from there.

When it is launched as a `LaunchAgent`, however, I get a return code of 9216 when attempting to access the keychain.  Here is the exact command sequence I have been using to test:

```
# Window 1
sudo launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup.plist
sudo launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup.plist
sudo launchctl debug system/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup --stdout --stderr

# Window 2
sudo launchctl kickstart -k -p system/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup
```

In the python script, I have been debugging by running a few subcommands and capturing output.

```
# OK
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput("security list-keychains")
logger.error("Keychain list :%s (retcode = %s)" % (
    output, status
))
# OK
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput("security find-generic-password -a 'Ionic Security' ")
logger.error("Keychain list item :%s (retcode = %s)" % (
    output, status
))
# Fails, with error code: 9216
# Prompts immediately when running from command line
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput("security find-generic-password -a 'Ionic Security' -g")
logger.error("Keychain access :%s (retcode = %s)" % (
    output, status
))
```

The output of that section of code looks like this:

```
# Correctly shows both keychains
ERROR:root:Keychain list :    "/Users/timothy/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain" (retcode = 0)
# Correctly lists information about keychain item
ERROR:root:Keychain list item :keychain: "/Users/timothy/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
<redacted>
# Fail
ERROR:root:Keychain access : (retcode = 9216)
```

These same commands work fine from the command line, with the last one (`-g`) resulting in a prompt to allow access to the keychain.

I have also tried opening up the entry for `com.ionicsecurity.client.sdk` in the `KeyChain Access` app, and set the "Allow all applications to access this item" radio button.  After doing that, grabbing the value from the cli no longer resulted in a prompt *but* the app returns the same error code.

I have searched for information about error code 9216 with no results.  Running the code through the `security errors` utility just gives

```
$ security error 9216
Error: 0x00002400 9216 unknown error 9216=2400
```

Any help on how I can get the application access to the keychain when running as a LaunchAgent would be much appreciated!

Comment: Possibly related: this is a user LaunchAgent, but the plist file has `root:wheel` permissions. I'm trying to figure out how to fix that here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290174/osx-syntax-for-loading-a-single-launchagent-for-current-user

Comment: It was 100% related. That started me down the right path when I tried to figure out how to launch the agent without `sudo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the domain that I was using to launch the LaunchAgent.  I was launching into the root system domain instead of the launching into the gui domain of the user I was setting up the LaunchAgent for.  Because of this

- The LaunchAgent did not have access to the users keychain (unless I requested the command run as the user with a session being created)
- The LaunchAgent did not have any way to display a pop up to the user to request access to the keychain (which I am assuming is why I got the strange error code here)

Here is the mapping from the commands I was using before (not working) to what I'm using now (working).  The commands assume the user for which we are installing the LaunchAgent is also the current user.

### Activating the agent

```
# Before
sudo launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup.plist

# Now
launchctl enable user/`id -u`/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup
launchctl bootstrap gui/`id -u` ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup.plist
```

### Deactivating the agent

```
# Before
sudo launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup.plist

# Now
launchctl bootout gui/`id -u`/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup
launchctl disable user/`id -u`/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup
```

### Setting permissions for the LaunchAgent definition (plist file)

```
# Before
chown root:wheel ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup.plist
chmod 644 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup.plist

# Now
chown "`id -un`":"`id -gn`" ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup.plist
chmod 644 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup.plist
```

### LaunchAgent plist file contents

The `UserName` and `SessionCreate` blocks are not needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/IonicFSWatcher.app/Contents/MacOS/ionic-fs-watcher</string>
        <string>/Users/timothy/ionicprotected</string>
        <string>--scan</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
```