# OSX: Syntax for loading a single launchagent for current user

Tags: macos, launchd, launchdagent

I am trying to load a single user's LaunchAgent plist.  All existing plist files in the directory have the permissions of the user and the user's default group,

If I use those permissions for my plist file and try to load, I get

```
$ sudo launchctl load -w -F $HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup.plist
/Users/timothy/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup.plist: Path had bad ownership/permissions
```

If I set the permissions to `root:wheel` the same command works.

I figured I was going about loading the wrong way, so I tried this:

```
sudo launchctl load -D user ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup.plist

# Similar result, just lots of `Operation not permitted` instead of `service already loaded`
launchctl load -D user com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup.plist
```

But from the 100s of lines of output it looks like that is trying to load every plist file that exists.

The docs from the tool seem to indicate that this would ONLY scan for plist files in `~/Libraries` (see below),

How do I load a LaunchAgent for the current user?

```
$ launchctl help load
Usage: launchctl load <service-path, service-path2, ...>
        -w      If the service is disabled, it will be enabled. In previous
                versions of launchd, being disabled meant that a service was
                not loaded. Now, services are always loaded. If a service is
                disabled, launchd does not advertise its service endpoints
                (sockets, Mach ports, etc.).
        -F      Forcibly load the service. This flag will ignore the service's
                disabled state. In previous versions of launchd, this flag
                would also ignore the ownership and permissions of the
                specified launchd.plist. This is no longer the case. Note that,
                unlike the -w flag, this flag will not  modify the service's
                disabled state; it will instead only ignore it for the load
                operation.
        -S <session>
                This flag takes a single argument which is the name of a
                session and may only be used when loading agents. All daemons
                exist within the same session, which is the system session.
                Agents may designate which sessions they can be loaded in with
                the LimitLoadToSessionType key.
        -D <domain>
                Loads launchd.plist(5) files from the specified domain.
                Depending on the current execution context, launchctl will look
                in a LaunchDaemons or LaunchAgents directory for
                launchd.plists. When running in the system's execution context
                (i.e. when run as root via a root shell or with sudo), the
                LaunchDaemons directory is searched. When running in a user's
                context (i.e. run normally from a shell), the LaunchAgents
                directory is searched. Valid domains are:
                system
                Searches /System/Library for either daemons or agents.

                local
                Searches /Library for either daemons or agents.

                network
                Searches /Network. This session type is no longer valid.

                user
                Searches the home directory of the calling user for agents
                only. Daemons may not be loaded from this
                domain.
```

Comment: First, you should probably be using the modern `launchctl` commands, unless you're trying to support legacy macOS versions. Specifically, use the `bootstrap` command, not `load`.

There's a lot of security in `launchd`. I recommend you start by checking the ownership of the executable your `.plist` refers to, and that your user can reach that resource. Also you need to check that your `.plist` settings are all appropriate for a user agent and you're not trying to do something like set the `UID` to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the prodding from [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5484406/james-bucanek) and [this excellent blog post](https://babodee.wordpress.com/2016/04/09/launchctl-2-0-syntax/), here is how to work with single user LaunchAgents on OSX (or at least on 10.11).

> The commands assume a plist file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup.plist`.

```
# Enable/disable
launchctl enable user/`id -u`/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup
launchctl disable user/`id -u`/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup

# Loading / unloading
launchctl bootstrap gui/`id -u` ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup.plist
launchctl bootout gui/`id -u`/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup

# Starting
sudo launchctl kickstart -k -p gui/`id -u`/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup

# Configure the next invocation of the service for debugging
# See `launchctl help debug` for more info 
sudo launchctl debug gui/`id -u`/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup --stdout --stderr

# Stopping
# You can send any valid signal: https://linux.die.net/Bash-Beginners-Guide/sect_12_01.html
launchctl kill SIGTERM gui/`id -u`/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup

# Get info for process
launchctl print gui/`id -u`/com.ionic.python.ionic-fs-watcher.startup
# For domain
launchctl print gui/`id -u`
# Enabled/disabled in domain
launchctl print-disabled gui/`id -u`
```

Comment: Brilliant. Hunted for a while for such good examples. Thank you.