# Do I need iPhone Developer license to run cordova/phonegap in ios simulator?

Tags: ios, cordova

I don't have an iPhone developer license.
It was working fine when I execute "cordova run ios"
Then I created a new project using "cordova create test_app"
When I run "cordova run ios", it throws this error.
Then the project that used to work is also failing with the same error?

```
Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No matching codesigning identity found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) matching “iPhone Developer” were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Error: /Users/Anthony/dev/test_app/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 65
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

Comment: Short answer: *No*, if you're running on iOS Simulator. 

Are you running the app on your iPhone device? In that case, yes you need to create a provisioning profile and code sign your app (iOS Developer Program enrollment needed).

Comment: so what settings do i need to change to stop it complaining? I just need to run it on simulator

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to have no device connected to the Mac else phonegap will try to build and deploy your app on it. I had the issue with my iPhone plugged in.
Also in Xcode be sure that you build the debug release with command line tools (in the info tab of project properties)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go over the solution in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19997804/3527656) - which tells you how to disabling Code Signing. Anyway, no harm in checking this -

Verify that the Code Signing section's Code Signing Identity within the project settings is set to *None* -

[image]

Search for *Code Signing* in Target of your app, and check if *Don't Code Sign* is chosen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ey

One thing is to play with XCode and Cordova to make a new project and learn how phonegap or another wrapper works and a different thing is to publish an application. Following the apple specifications, you can always create a new application and test it in the simulator. The benefits of becoming an apple developer are you can try your applications in a physical device but it doesnt mean you cant create an application and try it in the simulator.
If you have tried to run the application in a real device, XCode will complain about the required credentials because you are not an apple developer and you dont have your certificate installed in the keychain so the application cant be signed for deployment on a real device.
If you want to test the application in a device "Yes" you need to become an apple developer and pay the fee, if not, dont worry you can run as many applications as you want in the simulator.
Check the settings of your project as well to see if there is something wrong.