# No team selected for iOS build with VS Cordova tools

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, build, visual-studio-cordova

I am building an app for iOS with the Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3.1 from VS 2013. I have setup the environment on my Windows and Mac machines and I can build and run the app if I select an emulator. However, if I select **Local Device** then I get the following error:

> 1>MDAVSCLI : Code Sign error : No code signing identities found: No
>   valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair)
>   matching the team ID ΓÇ£(null)ΓÇ¥ were found. 1>MDAVSCLI : CodeSign
>   error : code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK
>   'iOS 8.3'

I have set-up a developer certificate and signing identity with XCode.

If I open the XCode project (available in *builds\buildid\cordovaApp\platforms\ios*) and go to General tab for the project and look at **Identity** I can see that no team is selected there. But I do have a team that I can select from the combo.

[image]

I suppose the error occurs because the actual team is not selected (therefore this **ΓÇ£(null)ΓÇ¥** in the error message). I have seen others having similar problems and told to set the team from here. However, I cannot do that, because the project file is generated with each build. I must setup this somehow from the VS Cordova tools. How do I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29956568/4815066

Comment: I think you should be targeting "Remote Device", rather than "Local Device".  If the device is connected to your Mac then it's a remote device.  What happens when you do that?

Comment: The problem seem to be with the signing identity. With an iOS Development certificate you can only build debug configs, and that works. To build release or distribution configs you need an iOS Distribution certificate, which is missing in my keychain setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, starting 4.3 of Cordova, the debug build requires a "development certificate" while Release & Distribution, both need a "distribution certificate" and matching provisioning profiles installed on the build machine. You can refer to the documentation that explains the process of getting these signing assets [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/tree/master/tutorial-package-publish).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I wasn't actually aware of that document. It's the kind of documentation one needs when starting with vs cordova tools, but it's what I've already found from various sources.

Answer (score 0):

I think you you should  confirm you certification is revoke. if it is revoke ,you should delete the old ceitification, then import the new one.

Comment: I don't have a problem with that. My problem was that I didn't have the iOS Distribution certificate in the keychain.