# Setting up Xcode 4 'Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment' as a post-build action

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, app-store, build-automation

I want to automate enterprise deployment as a post-build action which triggers after archiving, a script following these steps:

1. Use 'Distribute...' action in the Organizer for the latest archived build
2. Use the 'Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment' option
3. Select the pre-defined signing identity
4. Activate 'Save for Enterprise Distribution' and fill out the fields (URL, Title etc.)
5. Save the ipa and plist files in a given path

Is it possible to create a script automating these actions? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of these things can be done using the terminal, hence you can use it to build your apps for distribution. This post might help you a lot, it did help me when I wanted to do CI using Jenkins.

[Running xcodebuild from a forked terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577750/running-xcodebuild-from-a-forked-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use command line build tools to achieve the goal. The building and archiving actions in Xcode depend on these tools.

Refer to:

- [Xcode "Build and Archive" from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664885/xcode-build-and-archive-from-command-line)
- http://blog.octo.com/en/automating-over-the-air-deployment-for-iphone/
- http://nachbaur.com/blog/building-ios-apps-for-over-the-air-adhoc-distribution