# xcode building error

Tags: iphone, xcode, shell

I'm trying to build my own xcodeproject by running a shell script, and I'm getting this error after compiling most of the files.

```
CodeSign build/Release-iphoneos/moai.app
    cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/moai-test/workspace/moai-dev/xcode/ios
    setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "iPhone Distribution: Vanilla Breeze Co., Ltd." --resource-rules=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/moai-test/workspace/moai-dev/xcode/ios/build/Release-iphoneos/moai.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/moai-test/workspace/moai-dev/xcode/ios/build/MoaiSample.build/Release-iphoneos/moai.build/moai.xcent /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/moai-test/workspace/moai-dev/xcode/ios/build/Release-iphoneos/moai.app
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/moai-test/workspace/moai-dev/xcode/ios/build/Release-iphoneos/moai.app: User interaction is not allowed.
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

It seems like I'm having problems with distribution certificate, but I can't figure out what I should do.

Here is my shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
ProjectName="MoaiSample"
TargetName="moai"
SchemeName="MoaiSample"
#SDKS="iphoneos5.0"                                                                                                                                   
CONFIGURATIONS="Release"
ProvisionRelease=VBEnterpriseDistribution.mobileprovision
PASSWORD=password
IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: Vanilla Breeze Co., Ltd."
KEYCHAIN="/Users/vb_admin/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
PROJECT_PATH="/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/moai-test/workspace/moai-dev/xcode/ios "


# move to project folder

cd $PROJECT_PATH

# unlock security                                                                                                                                     
security unlock-keychain -p $PASSWORD $KEYCHAIN
# clean previous build files                                                                                                                          
xcodebuild -project $ProjectName.xcodeproj -target $TargetName -configuration $CONFIGURATIONS clean
# build project                                                                                                                                       xcodebuild -project $ProjectName.xcodeproj -target $TargetName -configuration $CONFIGURATIONS
# archive ipa file                                                                                                                                    #cd build                                                                                                                                             rm -Rf Payload $TargetName.ipa

mkdir Payload
cp -r build/Release-iphoneos/$TargetName.app Payload
zip -r $TargetName.ipa iTunesArtwork Payload
```

Any ideas on why my build fails?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read [Running xcodebuild from a forked terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577750/running-xcodebuild-from-a-forked-terminal)?

It seems like the keychain list can be different when running from the command line.

> The difference that most people have also seen is that if you run security list-keychain you'd get:

```
$ security list-keychain
  "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
  "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

> But when running in the ssh shell, I'd get:

```
$ security list-keychain
    "/Users/<i>user_account_name</i>/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

The recommendation is create a keychain not associated with a user account.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for a valid certificate for your app. Set the Provisioning Profile right and try again.