# How can I get the same result of "security" command in PHP code & in terminal on OSX apache?

Tags: php, ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I got the bellow result in the terminal on OSX

> macpro-terminal$ whoami
>   testuser
>   macpro-terminal$ groups
>   staff com.apple.access_screensharing everyone _appstore localaccounts _appserverusr admin _appserveradm _lpadmin _lpoperator _developer com.apple.sharepoint.group.1
>   macpro-terminal$ security list-keychains
>   "/Users/testuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain"
>   "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
>   macpro-terminal$ xcodebuild -project my.xcodeproj .........
>   ......(build result)..........
>   Build success

but, I got the different result in PHP code on OSX apache

## test.php

```
    $cpCommand = "whoami";
    $output = shell_exec($cpCommand);
    echo $output;

    $cpCommand = "groups";
    $output = shell_exec($cpCommand);
    echo $output;

    $cpCommand = "security list-keychains";
    $output = shell_exec($cpCommand);
    echo $output;

    $cpCommand = "xcodebuild -project my.xcodeproj ...........";
    $output = shell_exec($cpCommand);
    echo $output;
```

Result

> testuser
>   staff com.apple.access_screensharing everyone _appstore localaccounts _appserverusr admin _appserveradm _lpadmin _lpoperator _developer com.apple.sharepoint.group.1
>   "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
>   "/Library/Keychains/apsd.keychain"
>   "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
>   (comment : /Users/testuser/Library/Keychains/login.keychain -> is not exist)
>   [BEROR]Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution: testuser Co.,Ltd' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains
>   Build failed

I tried OS X 10.8 (mountain lion),built in apache2 & PHP.
What's problem?
How can I get the same result of "security" command in PHP code &  in terminal on OSX apache?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar problems but in my case it was attempting to do the build under Bamboo.

I can't tell you what you need to do in your case, but the answers in another question should point you in the right direction.

[Running xcodebuild from a forked terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577750/running-xcodebuild-from-a-forked-terminal)