# `security unlock-keychain` from a bash script

Tags: bash, macos, ssh, keychain, access-control-list

On MacOSX, if I ssh in and run the command:

```
security -v unlock-keychain -p <password> <keychain_path>
```

The keychain unlocks and all is well with the world.

If I put that same command into a bash script and run

```
bash test.sh
```

I get prompted for the password.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to explicitly let your script `test.sh` access your keychain.

- Open the Keychain Access
- Right click on the private key
- Select "Get Info"
- Select "Access Control" tab
- Click "Allow all applications to access this item"
- Click "Save Changes"
- Enter your password
- Enjoy

Credits: [Running xcodebuild from a forked terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577750/running-xcodebuild-from-a-forked-terminal/12235462#12235462)

Comment: Do I need to do this to every private key listed in the "keys" section of Keychain Access?

Comment: @CleverHuman I never did that, and I won't... I would consider this as a security issue if one of my script would access any of my private keys. I try to stick to the 1 function/1 key paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

In a weird twist, running `security unlock-keychain` from within screen or tmux might fail if some kind of security token has expired. I attempted to resolve this by modifying matching environment variables, but this failed. I had to ultimately abandon the screen session and start a new one.

An incomplete answer, but might be useful to others with a similar problem.