# How to run xcodebuild commands via ssh?

Tags: ios, xcode, ssh, xcodebuild

I am trying to run iOS tests with xcodebuild commands over ssh. When I try to run those commands which build and run the iOS UI Tests I am facing following error.

Note: I have all the keychains on the machine where I ssh in unlocked.

Command

```
HOME=/Users/mcj xcodebuild build-for-testing -project ios/ios_test_app/HXKPIIOS/HXKPIIOS.xcodeproj -scheme HXKPIIOS -destination 'platform=iOS,id=d623bacb04507071723fe1286c148edb822d5422' -derivedDataPath /opt/HXKPI_Logs/oobe_iOS_2018-06-14-11-14-23-216414/build_derived_data| tee /opt/HXKPI_Logs/oobe_iOS_2018-06-14-11-14-23-216414/uitest/build1.log
```

Error

```
 /usr/bin/codesign '-r-' '--display' '/opt/HXKPI_Logs/oobe_iOS_2018-06-14-11-14-23-216414/build_derived_data/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HXKPIIOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
/opt/HXKPI_Logs/oobe_iOS_2018-06-14-11-14-23-216414/build_derived_data/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HXKPIIOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: code object is not signed at all
Codesigning /opt/HXKPI_Logs/oobe_iOS_2018-06-14-11-14-23-216414/build_derived_data/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HXKPIIOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
  /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' '<code sign identity>' '--verbose' '/opt/HXKPI_Logs/oobe_iOS_2018-06-14-11-14-23-216414/build_derived_data/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HXKPIIOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
/opt/HXKPI_Logs/oobe_iOS_2018-06-14-11-14-23-216414/build_derived_data/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HXKPIIOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {
    /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' '<code sign identity>' '--verbose' '/opt/HXKPI_Logs/oobe_iOS_2018-06-14-11-14-23-216414/build_derived_data/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HXKPIIOS.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'
}

** TEST BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CopySwiftLibs /opt/HXKPI_Logs/oobe_iOS_2018-06-14-11-14-23-216414/build_derived_data/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HXKPIIOS.app
(1 failure)
```

Comment: When I try to run this command directly from the machine, it does work perfectly. Above mentioned error occurs when I ssh in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that although you have the proper items within your Keychain it still needs to be unlocked before it can execute the build process properly. When `ssh` in (before building) try:

```
$ security unlock-keychain
```

> <sub>If your keychain is not unlocked, it needs a window server connection
>   in order to prompt the user to unlock the keychain. Use security(1) to
>   unlock the keychain on the remote machine prior to executing the
>   xcodebuild.</sub>

If that doesn't work for you [please review this question and subsequent answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577750/running-xcodebuild-from-a-forked-terminal).

Comment: you can use the -p <PASSWORD> flag to unlock the keychain without a window server connection