# Flutter: Remote for mac show different result with the same terminal query for building the ipa file

Tags: ios, flutter, ssh, macos-sierra, xcodebuild

I'm working with flutter 3.0.4 and below code is running okay in terminal

```
flutter build ipa --no-sound-null-safety
```

But after I connect ssh to this mac from other mac with the same user

```
ssh panda@192.168.0.2
Password *****
flutter build ipa --no-sound-null-safety
```

- panda is my user name (admin role)
- 192.168.0.2 is my mac server local ip

And That show the problem

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-08-07 23:43:50.880 xcodebuild[35333:683754] Requested but did not find
    extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in
    com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-08-07 23:43:50.880 xcodebuild[35333:683754] Requested but did not find
    extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of
    plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** ARCHIVE FAILED **


Xcode's output:
```

I have tried multiple ways to fix problem above but it still does not work.

My macos: Monterey 12.5
Xcode version: 13.4.1(13F100)

Flutter doctor result:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.4, on macOS 12.5 21G72 darwin-x64, locale en-VN)
    • Flutter version 3.0.4 at /Users/panda/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 85684f9300 (5 weeks ago), 2022-06-30 13:22:47 -0700
    • Engine revision 6ba2af10bb
    • Dart version 2.17.5
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/panda/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.69.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.5 21G72 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 103.0.5060.134

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50881366/5558052)

The problem from the keychain is not unlock when connect through ssh.

You need to unlock that by

```
security unlock-keychain
```

Or with password

```
security unlock-keychain -p <password>
```

Thanks All